# How to return only the numbers in descending order using scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am new to functional language. 
I want to write a function that takes list of numbers as its parameter and returns a list identical to the parameter list except with the numbers in non-ascending order.

But I couldn't get the right result, what I got is:

```
(notAsc '(1 3 2 1 4 5))
'(3 2 5)
```

I think the good result should be '(3 2 1)
How could I modify it?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more examples. For instance, what's the expected output for `'(3 2 5 1)`? and for `'(1 2 3)`?. It's not clear if we should add _all_ the elements that appear in descending order, or just the longest sequence of them. Also, your implementation won't work, you should keep track of the previous element found in the sequence and add the current element only if it's less than the previous.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez you r right, just not sure how to track previous value in scheme. I think (3 2 5 1) should return (3 2 1) , (1 2 3)should return (3)

Comment: @flower no, to be consistent with (3 2 5 1) -> (3 2 1), the result for (1 2 3) should be  (1), and for (1 3 2 1 4 5) it's (1 1).

Comment: @ÓscarLópez (3 2 7 4 9 8 6 5 1) -> { (3 2 1) (7 4 1) (7 6 5 1) (9 8 6 5 1) } (and several more). which one to choose? probably the first; the OP never once used the word "longest".